# Is there a way to query Prometheus to count failed jobs in time range?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

There are several metrics collected for cron jobs, unfortunately I‘m not sure how to use them properly.

I wanted to use the `kube_job_status_failed == 1` metrics. I can use a regex for `job=~“+.myjobname.+“` to aggregate all failed attempts for a cron job.

This is where i got stuck. Is there a way to count the amount of distinct labels(=number of failed attempts) in a given time period?

Or can I use the metrics the other way around meaning checking whether there was `kube_job_status_succeeded{job=~“+.myjobname+.“}==1` in a given time period?

I feel like I’m so close to solving this but I just can’t wrap my head around it.

EDIT: Added Picture[This shows that there clearly are several succeded jobs over time, I just have no clue on how to count them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiwSw.png)

Comment: Do you want to count the amount of kube_job_status_failed == 1 for a specific job, or do you want the count of different jobs that failed

Comment: One cron job creates a job every n minute (naming it job_name=myjobname-{randomNums}) and I want to find the amount of jobs in a given period (with the name containing myjobname) having kube_status_failed == 1. so it basically is the same job started with a different name and I want to find the amount of jobs following that name pattern having this specific status.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the number of failed jobs matching the job name in 1h period:

```
count_over_time(kube_job_status_failed{job=~“+.myjobname+.“}==1 [1h])
```

Comment: This gives me a parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors.. :(

Comment: You can fix the errors on this by doing:

`count_over_time((kube_job_status_failed==1) [1h:])`

But it still won't give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this answer myself and found `offset` working for my purpose.

```
kube_job_failed{job_name=~"^your_job_name.*", namespace="your_teamspace",} - kube_job_failed{job_name=~"^your_job_name.*", namespace="your_teamspace",} offset 6h > 2
```

I needed 6h, not 1h and the amount of failed jobs to be larger than 2 in this timerange.

Answer (score 0):

Alright people, here is a somewhat gross way to do this that you can generalize for gauges that you only want to count the initial value of:

**Step 1:** Make it so you can count the gauge value just once (effectively count the amount of distinct labels):

```
sum(kube_job_failed{condition="true"} unless kube_job_failed offset 1m)
```

What you will see with this metric is a graph of job failures when they happen that don't persist after.

This is assuming a scrape interval of 1m.  If you scrape kube-state-metrics every 30s this will double count some and you should use 30s.  The way that this works is that we're doing a left anti-join with `unless` to remove all metrics in the range vector that existed 1 scrape interval earlier.  That will let you count the metrics just once, the first time they are scraped.

**Step 2:**

```
sum_over_time(sum(kube_job_failed{condition="true"} unless kube_job_failed offset 1m)[1h:]
```

This is going to sum the previous query for the time range you give it - in this case, the past 1 hour.